# Building a JMX client in a servlet installed on the Deployment Manager

Tags: client, websphere, admin, jmx

I'm building a monitoring application as a servlet running on my websphere 7 ND deployment manager.  The tool uses JMX to query the deployment manager for various data.  Global Security is enabled on the dmgr.

I'm having problems getting this to work however.  My first attempt was to use the websphere client code:

```
String sslProps = "file:" + base +"/properties/ssl.client.props";
System.setProperty("com.ibm.SSL.ConfigURL", sslProps);
String soapProps = "file:" + base +"/properties/soap.client.props";   
System.setProperty("com.ibm.SOAP.ConfigURL", pp);

Properties connectProps = new Properties();
connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE, AdminClient.CONNECTOR_TYPE_SOAP);
connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_HOST, dmgrHost);
connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_PORT, soapPort);
connectProps.setProperty(AdminClient.CONNECTOR_SECURITY_ENABLED, "true");
AdminClient adminClient = AdminClientFactory.createAdminClient(connectProps) ;
```

This results in the following exception:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.websphere.management.exception.ConnectorNotAvailableException: ADMC0016E: The system cannot create a SOAP connector to connect to host ssunlab10.apaceng.net at port 13903.
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.getUrl(SOAPConnectorClient.java:1306)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.access$300(SOAPConnectorClient.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient$4.run(SOAPConnectorClient.java:370)
    at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.reconnect(SOAPConnectorClient.java:363)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:209)
    at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.soap.SOAPConnectorClient.getUrl(SOAPConnectorClient.java:1286)
    ... 26 more
```

So, I then tried to do it via RMI, but adding in the sas.client.properties to the environment, and setting the connectort type in the code to CONNECTOR_TYPE_RMI.  Now though I got a NameNotFoundException out of CORBA:

```
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Context: , name: JMXConnector: First component in name JMXConnector not found. [Root exception is org.omg.CosNaming.NamingContextPackage.NotFound: IDL:omg.org/CosNaming/NamingContext/NotFound:1.0]
```

To see if it was an IBM issue, I tried using the standard JMX connector as well with the same result (substitute AdminClient for JMXConnector in the above error)

```
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/JMXConnector");
        Hashtable h = new Hashtable();
        String providerUrl = "corbaloc:iiop:" + dmgrHost + ":" + rmiPort + "/WsnAdminNameService";
        h.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl);

        // Specify the user ID and password for the server if security is enabled on server.
        String[] credentials = new String[] { "***", "***" };
        h.put("jmx.remote.credentials", credentials);

        // Establish the JMX connection.
        JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, h);

        // Get the MBean server connection instance.
        mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

At this point, in desperation I wrote a wsadmin sccript to run both the RMI and SOAP methods.  To my amazement, this works fine.  So my question is, why does the code not work in a servlet installed on the dmgr ?

regards,

Trevor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the SOAP error, the ConnectException looks like the wrong SOAP host/port was used for the dmgr.  I would double-check the server logs for the SOAP port.  For the RMI error (NameNotFoundException), it looks like you're trying to use JMXConnectorFactory, which isn't supported by WAS.

If your application is installed on the dmgr, it's probably easiest to just use AdminServiceFactory.getAdminService to get an in-process reference to the AdminService rather than trying to open a new connection to the same process:

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/fep/topic/com.ibm.websphere.javadoc.doc/web/apidocs/com/ibm/websphere/management/AdminServiceFactory.html

Comment: Your suggestion to use the AdminServiceFactory sounds like a good one.  I'll give it a try.  In regards to the SOAP suggestion, I'm sure the host and port are correct as the same ones work fine in the wsadmin script.

Comment: ... but it doesn't :(   The AdminServiceFactory works to a degree, but then falls over the first time you try to get WSStats from anything running outside the DMGR JVM.

Comment: The definitive answer is that you cannot connect via SOAP back to the JVM you are running in.  Kind of makes sense I guess

Comment: I've never heard of that restriction.  Interesting.